# Stop scrolling div overlap footer

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm making a scrolling div for every scroll, the div is a Google maps applet that shows records, however I want the div to stop scrolling once it has reached just before the footer so it does not overlap the footer, which it should stop above it (with a 10/20px margin from the bottom) so the content on the footer does not get overlapped and unable to be read.

I have this demo here which illustrates my code here at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5yC7/).

The yellow box should stay here when the scrolling has surpassed the footer position, like so:

[image]

The jsFiddle should get you an idea. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/baSBk/3/). I think this is what you're looking for

added another check to make sure the destination of the map doesn't go passed the footer before animating.

Comment: Hmmm. That fiddle you gave me doesn't work, it still overlaps the footer.

Comment: I would suggest changing: "top: thisWindow.scrollTop() - mapOffset.top + topMargin" to "top: destinationOffset".  To keep with the structure, I would also suggest modifying the variables a bit, "footer = $("#footer"), footerHeight = footer.height(), footerTop = footer.offset().top, footerOffestTop = footerTop - footerHeight" for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

My alternative:

http://jsfiddle.net/YRAmf/1/

was working on it only to find someone beet me to it :P

or more to my liking:

http://jsfiddle.net/YRAmf/3/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but the yellow div in your fiddle did not overlap the footer at all; it stopped about 20px above it. More details maybe?

Comment: Um, how big is your jsFiddle preview window (bottom right), because if you make it smaller, it can overlap it.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I would get the top position of the footer and put a conditional in your function that checks if the top offset of the map plus the 200px height of it are >= to the footer top offset. If so, stop the animation.